# Adding webapp server to namecheap domain that is already in use for gmail domain service

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, namecheap

I have setup a domain on namecheap and I'm currently using it for gmail/google workspace.
I would also like to deploy a webapp to the same domain - I have the site setup on digitalocean.
When I went through the process of adding the NS values to the domain panel in namecheap I realized it removed the server that allowed the email setup.

How do I safely service both the webapp and email servers from the same domain? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - namecheap doesn't support what I want to do.. I can either

1. Use the two services it does support (wix or weebly)
2. Handle the email domain setup from digitalocean

On further reflection this definitely makes sense, but I wish it were slightly easier :P